# How to modify javascript code to keep values from multiple html drop down menus

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 html drop down menu's and I try to keep the values selected after submitting the form

```
 <select name="select_zone" id="select_zone">
     <option value="a">A</option> 
     <option value="b">B</option>
     <option value="c">C</option>
 </select>
```

this is the javascript:

```
<script>
     document.getElementById("select_zone").onchange = function() {
        localStorage['select_zone'] = document.getElementById("select_zone").value;
       }
       window.onload= function(){
           if(localStorage['select_zone'])
               document.getElementById("select_zone").value = localStorage['select_zone'];
       }
   </script>
```

This works, but the problem is that if I copy the code 2 more times for the other drop down menus, only 1 menu at a time keep the values.
How would you change the js code so that all menu's keep the values?

Comment: different `id`s...

Comment: `<select name="select_zone" id="select_zone_1">`, `<select name="select_zone_2" id="select_zone_3">`, and `<select name="select_zone" id="select_zone">`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give 3 different ids, something like that (not tested):

```html
 <select name="select_zone_1" id="select_zone_1">
     <option value="a">A</option> 
     <option value="b">B</option>
     <option value="c">C</option>
 </select>
 <select name="select_zone_2" id="select_zone_2">
     <option value="a">A</option> 
     <option value="b">B</option>
     <option value="c">C</option>
 </select>
 <select name="select_zone_3" id="select_zone_3">
     <option value="a">A</option> 
     <option value="b">B</option>
     <option value="c">C</option>
 </select>
```

Javascript:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    let id = `select_zone_${i}`;
    document.getElementById(id).onchange = function() {
        localStorage[id] = document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        if (localStorage[id]) {
            document.getElementById(id).value = localStorage[id];
        }
    }
}
```

You can remove the `name` attribute if you don't need it elsewhere.

**EDIT**

In order to be more reliable, you can try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <select class="storable" id="select_zone_1">
     <option value="a">A</option> 
     <option value="b">B</option>
     <option value="c">C</option>
 </select>
 <select class="storable" id="select_zone_2">
     <option value="a">A</option> 
     <option value="b">B</option>
     <option value="c">C</option>
 </select>
 <select class="storable" id="select_zone_3">
     <option value="a">A</option> 
     <option value="b">B</option>
     <option value="c">C</option>
 </select>

 <script>
     function getStorableElements() {
         return document.querySelectorAll('.storable');
     }

     for (const element of getStorableElements()) {
         element.onchange = () => localStorage[element.id] = element.value;
     }

     window.onload = () => {
         for (const element of getStorableElements()) {
             const id = element.id;
             if (localStorage[id]) {
                 element.value = localStorage[id];
             }
         }
     }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course, I have all id's different. Your JS gives me an type error